# how can i sum data fetch in sql query

Tags: mysql

Am trying to sum a result of column from my sql query,

I have a table of  four columns (user_id, items, qty and price) which I want to multiply (qty * price) as 'total' and then sum(total) as final_result

This is the code I tried,

```
SELECT SUM(`total`) AS 'final_total' FROM (SELECT `column_price` * `column_qty` AS `total` FROM `table_name` WHERE user_id = 'john');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine other than that the subquery is missing a required alias:

```sql
SELECT SUM(total) AS final_total
FROM (
    SELECT column_price*column_qty AS total
    FROM table_name
    WHERE user_id = 'john'
) t;
```

But, we don't even need the subquery, q.v. this version:

```sql
SELECT SUM(column_price*column_qty) AS final_total
FROM table_name
WHERE user_id = 'john';
```